# GCC/Clang -gdwarf option in combination of -g option

Tags: c, gcc, clang, debug-symbols

[GCC debug documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) mentions that

> `-gdwarf` does not accept a concatenated debug level, to avoid confusion with `-gdwarf-level`. Instead use an additional `-glevel` option to change
> the debug level for `DWARF`.

So I tried compiling a binary with options `-g0 -gwarf` and in gdb it looks like `-g0` was ignored and `-gdwarf` implicitly changed it to `-g2`. `-g3 -gwarf` in turns generates the actual `-g3` information (macro expansion is possible).

The behavior is not really clear from the documentation.

How does combination `-glevel -gdwarf` actually work?

Comment: Do you see different behavior with `-gdwarf` `-g0`?  Order of command-line options sometimes matters.

Comment: But in any case, if you don't want debug information (`-g0`) then how is it useful to specify that the information that is not to be produced would be in DWARF format if it were produced?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed `-gdwarf -g0` produces no debug information. The thing is I expected `-g1 -gdwarf` to produce no information about local variables, but it's compiled as with `-g2`. Changing the order to `-gdwarf -g1` does the job. `-g3` seems to take precedence despite the order.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Anyway it's not obvious that `-gdwarf` implicitly sets `-g2`

Comment: It is natural that `-gdwarf` overrides `-g0`, but I agree that it is surprising for it to override `-g1` yet not `-g3`.